# TableLayout not refreshing after findViewById

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I am trying to render news articles based on a few toggle buttons in a fragment. The articles show up when the correct button (allButton) is clicked, but don't disappear. Here is my code:

```
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        ToggleButton allButton = (ToggleButton) root.findViewById(R.id.allButton);
        ToggleButton readButton = (ToggleButton) root.findViewById(R.id.readButton);
        ToggleButton unreadButton = (ToggleButton) root.findViewById(R.id.unreadButton);
        //TableLayout table = (TableLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.newsTable);
        //showArticles(root, table, allButton, readButton, unreadButton);
        allButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    //buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    buttonView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    unreadButton.setChecked(false);
                    allButton.setChecked(true);
                    readButton.setChecked(false);
                    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.newsTable);
                    showArticles(root, table, allButton, readButton, unreadButton);
                } else {
                    //buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    buttonView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        });
        readButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    //buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    buttonView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    allButton.setChecked(false);
                    readButton.setChecked(true);
                    unreadButton.setChecked(false);
                    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.newsTable);
                    showArticles(root, table, allButton, readButton, unreadButton);
                } else {
                    //buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    buttonView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        });

        unreadButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    //buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    buttonView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    allButton.setChecked(false);
                    unreadButton.setChecked(true);
                    readButton.setChecked(false);
                    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.newsTable);
                    showArticles(root, table, allButton, readButton, unreadButton);
                } else {
                    //buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    buttonView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        });

        return root;
```

Please note that the showArticles edits the TableLayout passed directly. I thought that each time I called root.findViewById(), that the TableLayout would refresh to only the XML layout (disregarding programmatic additions), but it seems to keep the new tablerows added. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!